# Elementary question on probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Villages A,B,C, and D are connected by overhead telephone lines joining AB, AC, BC, BD, and CD. As a result of severe gales, there is a probability p(the same for each link), that any particular link is broken.

**(a)** Show that the probability that a call can be made from A to B = $1-p^2-2p^3+3p^4-p^5$

**(b)** Show that the probability that a call can be made from D to A = $1-2p^2-2p^3+5p^4-2p^5$

I tried the problem in this way:

**(a)** Probability of a call failure from A to B

= [AB(x),AC(x)] + [AB(x),AC(ok),CB(x),CD(ok),DB(x)] + [AB(x),AC(ok),CB(x),CD(x)]

=$p^2+p^3(1-p)^2+p^3(1-p)$

$=p^2+2p^3-3p^4+p^5$

So, probability of success = $1-p^2-2p^3+3p^4-p^5 (proved)$

(b)** probability of call failure from D to A,

=

[DB(x),DC(x)]+[DB(x),DC(ok),CA(x),CB(x)]+[DB(x),DC(ok),CA(x),CB(ok),BA(x)]

+[DC(x),DB(ok),BA(x),BC(x)]+[DC(x),DB(ok),BA(x),BC(ok),CA(x)]

$=p^2+p^3(1-p)+p^3(1-p)^2+p^3(1-p)+p^3(1-p)^2$

$=p^2+4p^3-6p^4+2p^5$

I have applied the same concept in determining **(b)** as the one used in proving **(a)**. Where am I making the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part b), you missed a case with, in your notation, [DB(ok), DC(ok), BA(x), CA(x)].